# Merging JQuery & Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using some JavaScript to copy a value when an input is clicked. This works well.
Normally I do a JavaScript alert, but now I would like to use a query fading div.

If I run the jquery or javascript in separate scripts then they work fine, as soon as I join them they fail.

I think this is because I use a onMouseOver for the copy, but an input click event for the fading alert.

Any idea how I can merge these ?

```
<script language="JavaScript">
        function toClip(me,vals) {
                var clip = new ZeroClipboard.Client();
                clip.setHandCursor( true );
                clip.setText(vals);
                clip.glue(me);
        }
</script>

<script  type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
$('input').click(function() {
    $messageCont = $('<div class="message_cont">');
    $message = $('<div>DONE</div>').hide();
    $messageCont.append($message);
    $('body').prepend($messageCont);
    $messageCont.css({
    "left" : $(this).offset().left,
    "top" : $(this).offset().top
    });
    $message.fadeIn(200, function() {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $messageCont.fadeOut();
            //code to clean up container
        }, 1500)
    })
 })
});
$messageCont.css({
    "left" : $(this).offset().left,
    "top" : $(this).offset().top
});
</script>
```

This is called via :

```
<div class='copy' onmouseOver="toClip(this,'$val')"><input type="button" value="Copy"/></div>
```

Thanks :)

UPDATE 15th April:

Sort of got this working using jquery instead of Javascript.

```
<input type="button" id="copy_button" data-clipboard-text="Copy Me!" Value="Click ME">
<script src="js/ZeroClipboard.js"></script>
<script>
var clip = new ZeroClipboard( document.getElementById("copy_button"), {
  moviePath: "js/ZeroClipboard.swf"
} );

clip.on( 'complete', function(client, args) {
var $message = $('<div class="message">DONE</div>').hide();
var $messageCont = $('<div class="message_cont" />').append($message).prependTo('body');
$messageCont.css({
   "left" : $(this).offset().left,
   "top" : $(this).offset().top
}).find("div.message").fadeIn(200).delay(1500).fadeOut(function() {
        });
   } );
</script>
```

Only issue I have is it only works with on button. I have lots I'd like it to work with.
Anyone know how to resolve that ?

Thanks :)

Comment: What do you mean by *join* and *merge*?

Comment: jQuery ***IS*** JavaScript.

Comment: How do they fail? Do you get an error message?

Comment: Why are you using language='javascript' in the first script tag and type='text/javascript' in the second? The language attribute is deprecated.

Comment: Sorry these have come from two separate scripts and I've not tidied them up as yet. What I want to do is click the input button have the value copied to clipboard and then have the div floater show up. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several points :

- New `$messageCont/$message` probably don't need to be created each time an input is clicked? The rest of the code suggests reuse.
- The `$messageCont = ...` expression has incomplete HTML. You must ensure the div tag is closed, either with `<div>...</div>` or with `<div />`.
- The script fades in `$message` but fades out `$messageCont`. This is OK on first use, but you will see precisely nada subsequently; there's no expression to fade `$messageCont` back in.
- Delay in an animation queue can be achieved with `.delay()`, which is cleaner than using `setTimeout()`.
- It's hard to see what the second `$messageCont.css(...)` expression is supposed to achieve when `$messageCont` is positioned before it's contents are shown. If it is necessary to position `$messageCont` initially, then it's better to do so with a stylesheet directive, or in jQuery inside the $(document).ready(function() {...}) structure.

Reading between the lines, I think you probably want something more like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $message = $('<div class="message">DONE</div>').hide();
    var $messageCont = $('<div class="message_cont" />').append($message).prependTo('body');
    $('input').on('click', function() {
        $messageCont.css({
            "left" : $(this).offset().left,
            "top" : $(this).offset().top
        }).find("div.message").fadeIn(200).delay(1500).fadeOut(function() {
            //code to clean up container
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That doesn't see to work for me. ! When I click an input button nothing happens

Comment: Thanks that now works, if I don't have the other Javascript being called via the onMouseOver - but I need that so I can copy the underlying value to the clipboard ?

Is there anyway to get the 2 sections of code to work together ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Presumably ZeroClipboard is successfully installed on the page? If not then `... new ZeroClipboard.Client()` will throw an error to the browser's error console.

Comment: Hi. Sort of got it working using Jquery. But only for one button.
I've updated my original post.. any suggestions welcome !

Comment: I've accepted this as it does work, but isn't quite what I wanted.
That is my fault as I didn't ask very clearly.
Thanks

Comment: My problem is not really understanding ZeroClipboard. No time to go research it right now.